# Questions about a wiring diagram of a transducer

Tags: wiring, diagram, transducer

I have an old current output wind-meter with the following diagram:

[image]

Unfortunately there is no online documentation about the device so I had to take the above photo.

1. I'm curious what could be the the parallel vertical symbols around at some junctions as shown in the upper red question mark?
2. The gn(green) and br(brown) wires seem to already be connected to each other inside the transducer. What could be the reason they are showing a connection needed outside of the transducer as in the bottom red question mark?

Comment: [Feed-through capacitors](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-q00r1ekVvMY/VrIRGNFrEPI/AAAAAAAABxw/ya8mcb4ebdA/s1600/more-capacitor-symbol.gif) for (1).

Comment: @Andyaka The photo of such capacitor is shown here: https://passive-components.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Feedthrough-capacitors.jpg The symbol has three terminals but the photo has two terminals. Is the third terminal in this case the outer body?

Comment: yes, the body will be the third terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect those are coaxial wall-mounted bypass capacitors, such as by Johanson, for excluding RF from the circuits.

Answer (score 0):

- 1. Those symbols appear to be "guards" it appears they really wanted to keep the noise down, essentially a ground that wraps around the signal., in this case it appears tied to the chassis of the device.
- 2. while they are connected, I presume they are handled slightly differently, e.g. green runs to the power wiring, while brown is intended to the return wire for the gauge, likely again to reduce the amount of noise coupled in, I would call that lower question mark wire optional, but may be a reflection that the input your feeding the signal to may not have a seperate exposed ground pin, meaning it ends up tied to the same supply ground in practice.

Comment: I agree with Andy aka, #1 is a feed-through cap. The cap is usually drawn at the chassis boundary.